# Get class name of class

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Groovy beginner, coming from Java / Kotlin, how do I get the class name of an (anonymous) implementation of my class?

Failed attempts:

```
abstract class Foo {
    String name() { this.class.simpleName }
}

abstract class Foo {
    String name() { return this.class.simpleName }
}

abstract class Foo {
    String name() { return getClass().getSimpleName() }
}

abstract class Foo {
    String name() { this.metaClass.classNode.nameWithoutPackage }
}
```

So obviously I seem to give some class instance a default name. I thought "well, if class name does not work, let's try individual naming" with this:

```
abstract class Foo {
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0)
    String name() { "number " + this.counter.incrementAndGet() }
}
```

but this doesn't work either because `counter is not a property of groovy.lang.Binding`.

This is all in context of a Jenkins pipeline I try to write... why is this so hard?

Comment: "why is this so hard?" - It isn't.  You have made up method and property names that don't exist and that won't work but if you refer to `this.class.name`, that should work.

Comment: Note that except in cases where special property access interception is happening, all of the following are equivalent... `this.class.name`, `this.getClass().name`, `this.getClass().getName()`, `this.class.getName()`.  Idiomatic Groovy would be `this.class.name`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want this...

```
abstract class Foo {
    String name() { this.class.name }
}
```

Comment: The above code does what you are asking, but this is an unusual thing to do.  If you have a reference to an instance of the subclass (anonymous or otherwise) you can simply refer to `myInstance.class.name`.  You don't need to write a `name()` method.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I was so in Java mode and concentrated on `simpleName` (which also exists in the API, but returns an empty string) to skip the package path that I actually haven't tried `name`.

Comment: I also see that `this.class.name` doesn't bring me any further, as it is set to `WorkflowScript$1` instead of the `Bar` (for `class Bar extends Foo {}`), so is there idiomatically anything wrong with my `AtomicInt` implementation?

Comment: I ultimatively get there `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: counter for class: groovy.lang.Binding`